# How to make a toggle function

Tags: javascript

I’m somewhat new to JavaScript and I made a function that changes text when clicked but how can I make the text change back if you click it again? I would include a screenshot but I don’t have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Don't include a screenshot, include *code*. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please include code samples.

Comment: HTML can not be changed once the page has been loaded using HTML. You can achieve this functionality by using JavaScript however. Take a look here for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Simple. Just use a toggle variable.

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me.</p>

<script>
var toggle = 0;
function myFunction() {
    var el = document.getElementById("demo");
    if(toggle == 0){
        el.innerHTML = "ZERO";
        toggle = 1;
    }
    else{
        el.innerHTML = "ONE";
        toggle = 0;
    }

}
</script>
```

**Run it [Here](https://codepen.io/sirajalam049/pen/vWyVvR)**

Answer (score 0):

the most basic and simplest way is to use three variables-

programming in scala in fun

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $elem = $('#para');
 var text1 = $elem.text();
 var text2 = 'Rust is trending language of 2017';
 var toggled = false;
 $elem.on('click', function()) {
  if(!toggled) {
  $elem.text(text2);
  toggled = true;
 }
 else {
  $elem.text(text1)
  toggled = false;
 }
});
</script>
```